# Problems with connection Hibernate to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

Firstly it's my first post here so sorry for that.

I am doing a Udemy course Hibernate & JPA and i have problem here.

I mean Im doing everything like a person from which am studing but a have problems to run a program.

I don't know how to deal with it.
I'm using Eclipse and for MySql is MySQL Workbench.

There is a my project -> [click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXpVA15xQ9eGsFub5qgXgZTafl47PFwP/view?usp=sharing)

and a guy's project from a Udemy -> [click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lOYJvsGzLAavEpzykFNR9d617BJ8-pbs/view?usp=sharing)

When i want to run program a i have this problems

```
    WARN - HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
INFO - HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances]
INFO - HHH000046: Connection properties: {password=skills, user=infinite}
INFO - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
INFO - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
DEBUG - Initializing Connection pool with 1 Connections
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value '?rodkowoeuropejski czas letni' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value '?rodkowoeuropejski czas letni' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:134)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2186)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2209)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1318)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
    ... 19 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.infiniteskills.data.Application.main(Application.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error building the factory
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:22)
    at com.infiniteskills.data.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    ... 1 more



Its my hibernate.cfg.xml file :

package com.infiniteskills.data;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        
        User user = new User();
        user.setBirthDate(new Date());
        user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        user.setCreatedBy("kevin");
        user.setEmailAddress("kmb@yahoo.com");
        user.setFirstName("Kevin");
        user.setLastName("Bowersox");
        user.setLastUpdatedBy("kevin");
        user.setLastUpdatedDate(new Date());
        
        
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

hibernate.properties file :

```
hibernate.connection.username= infinite
hibernate.connection.password= skills
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

log4j.properties file :

```
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
```

Application.java file:

```
package com.infiniteskills.data;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        
        User user = new User();
        user.setBirthDate(new Date());
        user.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        user.setCreatedBy("kevin");
        user.setEmailAddress("kmb@yahoo.com");
        user.setFirstName("Kevin");
        user.setLastName("Bowersox");
        user.setLastUpdatedBy("kevin");
        user.setLastUpdatedDate(new Date());
        
        
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

HibernateUtil.java file:

```
   package com.infiniteskills.data;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            return configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                            .build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "There was an error building the factory");
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

and my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.infiniteskills</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-course</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hibernate-course</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

EDIT 1:
There is another problem ->

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User

User.java File:

```
package com.infiniteskills.data.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity

@Table(name="FINANCES_USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;

    @Column(name="LAST_UPDATED_BY")
    private String lastUpdatedBy;

    @Column(name="CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name="CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove space before user/password and use a valid timezone

Comment: Set a default time zone as described here: https://mkyong.com/jdbc/java-sql-sqlexception-the-server-time-zone-value-xx-time-is-unrecognized/

Answer (score 1):

Update hibernate.properties and add serverTimeZone property in JDBC connection string directly..

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ifinances?serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: It helps a lot but still i have another error: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User

Comment: User should be Marked as Entity annotation with Id(Primary Key) mapping, If already done show the code.

Comment: I think it's already done I code. User file is added on the top.

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem with this project.

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.infiniteskills.data.entities.User

I added above a code from User.java